# reinstall recent ubuntu update MOK

Tags: 18.04, secure-boot

It appears after a recent update, Ubuntu installs 2 MOK keys. I plan to restore factory default MOKs because there are some MOKs that I don't recognize. How can reinstall that update MOKs after that? That update was NOT a 3rd party driver

Possible key:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PxuyyphrYeRiHV2AtPHLVIzp3xvGcz75/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What's a "MOK"?

Comment: @waltinator Machine Owner Key (secure boot)

Comment: I attached what I think was the key @waltinator